# Why is unit testing harder in Object Oriented programming compared to Functional programming?

Tags: object-oriented, unit-testing, functional-programming

I'm going through this [series](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/13-ways-of-looking-at-a-turtle/). The author mentions that since state is maintained in object oriented programming, it is harder to write unit tests. He also says that since functional programming doesn't maintain state (not always), it is easier to write unit tests. I didn't see any examples that demonstrate this problem. If this is true, could you provide me an example comparing unit testing in object oriented and functional programming?

Comment: I disagree with idea that functional programming is easier to test. While it is true stateless function is easier to test than stateful object, converting stateful object into stateless function results in much more complex stateles function, possibly with some complex state-emulation, like monads.

Comment: @Euphoric A functional rendition of a solution to a problem is likely to be quite different than just replacing state with a `State` monad (which emulates state). You partially have a point - code written in that style does have non-local interactions - but for the purposes of unit testing you still can just explicitly pass in the state, you don't have to mock anything. On the other hand, with monads like `ST` and `IO` (which have true, implicit mutable state), you simply *are* doing stateful programming, and unit testing it will be no easier than in any other language.

Comment: There is *nothing* in the definition of OO that requires mutable state. It is perfectly possible (and widely done) to write pure, referentially-transparent OO code.

Comment: All of the techniques associated with functional programming are perfectly applicable in object-oriented programming. Well designed OO programs typically use functional techniques at the lower levels, at a minimum.

Comment: @JörgWMittag how would you make an int or decimal fields in c# immutable? Using constants is not a very good strategy.

Comment: @user3587180 - just do not change existed variables - and always create new.

Comment: @Fabio If that is the case it makes more sense to use FP programming. OO does not require mutable state, but mutability is implicit in the example I just gave you. Same goes for f# - you can mark a variable mutable to fit oo needs. But if you are going to use too many mutable variable, you might as well use c#.

Comment: @user3587180: You would make an `int` or `decimal` field immutable the same way you make any other field immutable: make it `readonly` and don't provide a setter. I'm not sure what you mean by "using constants is not a good strategy". In functional programming, every "variable" is a "constant" (since in FP, variables don't actually "vary"), and it seems to work just fine for them.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I know I can mark it as read only. But if I were to mark majority of my fields as read only, I'd rather pick a functional programming language since all the variables are immutable by default. So that tells me that OO and FP were designed with different plans in mind.

Comment: @user3587180: Why do you assume that your hypothetical OO language would not have immutable as default?

Comment: @JörgWMittag not hypothetical - c# is what I had in my mind. Sorry, my intention was not to say you are wrong or I'm right. I'm new FP so have a lot of questions and confusions.

Comment: @user3587180 Ever heard of Rust?  Immutability by default and also object oriented.   Being an OO language does not mean "implicit mutability" in the slightest, that is a *language design* decision agnostic from what kind of archetype the language is.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I want to distinguish between two different ways of approaching object oriented programming

1. Simulationist: your objects represent real domain objects, you've programmed them to handle any functionality related to that domain. Objects programmed in this way are likely to have a lot of mutable state and hidden collaborators used to implement this functionality.
2. Records+functions: your objects are just bundles of data and functions that operates over that data. Objects programmed in this way are more apt to be immutable, to take on less responsibilities and allow one to inject collaborators.

A rule of thumb is that an object programmed in the first way is going to have more methods and more `void` methods than in the second way. Say we were going to write a flight simulator and were designing a plane class. We would have something like:

```
class Plane {
    void accelerate();
    void deccelerate();
    void toggleRightFlaps();
    void toggleLeftFlaps();
    void turnRudderRight();
    void turnRudderLeft();
    void deployLandingGear();
    void liftLandingGear();
    // etc.
    void tick() throws PlaneCrashedException;
}
```

This is maybe a little more extreme than one might encounter, but it gets the point across. If you want to implement this sort of interface you have to keep inside the object:

1. All the information about the state of the plane's equipment.
2. All the information about the velocity / acceleration of the plane.
3. The refresh rate of our simulation (to implement tick).
4. Full details about the 3d model of the simulation and its physics to implement tick.

Writing a unit test for an object written in the mode is dead hard because:

1. You need to supply all of the many different bits of data and collaborators this object needs at the start of your test (instatiating these can be really tedious).
2. When you want to test a method you run into two problems: a) the interface frequently does not expose enough data for you to test (so you end up having to use mocks / reflection to even verify expectations) b) there are many components bound into one that you have to verify behaved in each test.

Basically you start with an interface that looks kind of reasonable and like it fits the domain well, but the niceness of the simulation has beguiled you into creating an object that's really hard to test.

However, you can create objects that would fulfill the same purpose. You would want to brake your `Plane` out into smaller bits. Have a `PlaneParticle` that tracks the physicsy bits of the plane, the position, velocity, acceleration, roll, yaw, etc., etc., exposing and allowing one to manipulate these. Then a `PlaneParts` object could track the status of. You would ship `tick()` to a completely different place, say have a `PlanePhysics` object parameterized by, e.g., the force of gravity, that knows given a `PlaneParticle` and a `PlaneParts` how to spit out a new `PlaneParticle`. All of this could be fully immutable, though it need not be for some example.

You now have these advantages in terms of testing:

1. Each individual component has less to do and is easier to set up.
2. You can test your components in isolation.
3. These objects can get away with exposing their internals (especially if they're made immutable), so one needs no cleverness to measure them.

Here's the trick: the second object-oriented approach I described is very close to functional programming. Maybe in pure functional programs your records and your functions are separate and not bound together in objects, definitely a functional program would ensure that all of these things. What I think really makes unit testing easy is

1. Small units (small state space).
2. Functions with minimal input (no hidden inputs).
3. Functions with minimal output.

Functional programming encourages these things (but one can write bad programs in any paradigm) but they are achievable in object-oriented programs. And I would further stress that functional programming and object-oriented programming are not incompatible.

Comment: I am not sure this is a good distinction. Even when using approach 1, many would consider the techniques you describe for approach 2 to be standard practice. The two approaches are not mutually exclusive. The bits of the Plane can be composed together to create a larger abstraction, and you are now in the area of approach 1. I would go as far as saying approach 1, as you describe it, is not logical.

Comment: "And I would further stress that functional programming and object-oriented programming are not incompatible.": Some would say that object-oriented programming is characterized only by dynamic dispatch. So you can write in **imperative** OOP style: mutable objects + dynamic dispatch, or in **functional** OOP style: immutable objects + dynamic dispatch.

Comment: Breaking 1 big object into smaller parts is not functional programming. And the solution to a big object is **not** to separate the logic from the data and make it anemic, *which is functional*. I might be misunderstanding your whole **however** part though.